# Change property descriptor (enumerable) from within TypeScript decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator, propertydescriptor

I just wanted to share the results of a brief struggle with TypeScript decorators.

I was trying to do change a property descriptor from within a property decorator, e.g. in order to make a property enumberable:

```
export function MyPropDecorator<T>(options: {enumerable: boolean, <other options...> }) {
    return function (target: any, key: string): any {
        let type = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
        let pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
        pd.enumerbale = options.enumerable;
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, pd);
        ...
    }
}
```

But as soon as the decorator function was left, "eumerable" was somehow changed back to "false". The problem is that one **must not** call "Object.defineProperty" within a property decorator because the TypeScript "__decorate" function will overwrite it. 
**The trick is to return the modified property descriptor**:

```
export function MyPropDecorator<T>(options: {enumerable: boolean, <other options...> }) {
    return function (target: any, key: string): any {
        let type = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
        let pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
        pd.enumerbale = options.enumerable;
        return pd;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should re-write it more like a question and then put your solution as an answer and accept it. It will be easier for future readers and will let you get reputation with upvotes

Comment: It's probably for the best to copy the descriptor instead of using the original one: `let pd = Object.assign({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key))`

Comment: I think this will close, but I will be happy to reopen it again if it can be presented in a Q&A format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as helpful as it is, it is an answer without a question.

Comment: Thanks for the finding. I've struggled with this issue for hours and finally got the working answer.